# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User". Use mongoose.model(name, schema) with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mern

I am learning typescript now so I am new to it, so I am shifting the project from js to ts. while the database connection is being established correctly I am getting the above error when I am trying to call a test get request which get all the prompts from the prompts collection.

Here's are the codes

Models
User.ts

```
import { Schema, model, InferSchemaType } from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, "Email already exists"],
    required: [true, "Email is required"],
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Username is required"],
    match: [
      /^(?=.{8,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/,
      "Username invalid, it should contain 8-20 alphanumeric letters and be unique!",
    ],
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
});

type UserType = InferSchemaType<typeof UserSchema>;

const User = model<UserType>("User", UserSchema);

export default User;
```

Prompts.ts

```
import {Schema, model, InferSchemaType} from 'mongoose';

const PromptSchema = new Schema({
    creator: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    prompt: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Prompt is required"],
    },
    tag: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Tag is required"],
    }
});

type PromptType = InferSchemaType<typeof PromptSchema>

const Prompt = model<PromptType>("Prompt", PromptSchema);

export default Prompt;
```

dbconfig.ts

```
import mongoose, { ConnectOptions } from "mongoose";
import User from "../models/users";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const mongouri: string = process.env.MONGODB_URI as string;

const dbOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  dbName: "share_prompt",
} as ConnectOptions;

export const connectDb = () => {
  mongoose
    .connect(mongouri, dbOptions)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Database Connected Successfully!!");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Could not connect to the database", err);
      process.exit(1);
    });
};

User //if I add this line than the error goes away
```

controller.ts

```
import Prompt from "../models/prompts";
import User from "../models/users";
import { Request, Response } from "express";

// get all prompts
export const getAllPrompts = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const prompts = await Prompt.find({}).populate("creator");
    res.status(200).json(prompts);
  } catch (error: String | any) {
    console.log(error);

    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

Index.ts

```
/**
 * Required External Modules
 */
import { connectDb } from "./config/dbConfig";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import { router } from "./routes/promptsRoutes";
import helmet from "helmet";

dotenv.config();

/**
 * App Variables
 */
if (!process.env.PORT) {
  process.exit(1);
}

const PORT: number = parseInt(process.env.PORT as string, 10);

const app = express();

/**
 *  App Configuration
 */
app.use(helmet());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api", router);

/**
 * Server Activation
 */
connectDb();

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello there the server is running just fine." });
});
```

I have tried chatgpt and stackoverflow and other articles I can find on the internet but nothing helped, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I don't use mongoose with TypeScript all that often but I see `InferSchemaType` in the User.ts so try creating the model like `const User = model('User', UserSchema);` instead.

Comment: Tried it, still got the same error